# How to remove an object from std::vector?

Tags: vector, std

ALL,

Consider following code:

```
class CPlayer
{
public:
    CPlayer(bool new) { m_new = new; };
    bool IsNewPlayer() { return m_new; }
private:
    bool m_new;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<CPlayer> players_pool;
    players_pool.push_back( false );
    players_pool.push_back( false );
    players_pool.push_back( true );
    players_pool.push_back( false );
}
```

Now what I'm looking for is to remove the players which has m_new as true.

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
players_pool.erase( std::remove( players_pool.begin(), players_pool.end(), players_pool.at().IsNewPlayer() ), players_pool.end() );
```

Now everywhere the examples given are for simple integers and not for the class objects.

Is there an easy way to perform such an operation?

And I need it to work in MSVC 2010 and XCode 4 with 10.6 SDK.

**Note**: The code given is a simplified version of the actual code I'm working on. Class CPlayer has a lot more fields than I put here but they are not relevant to this post.

Thank you.

P.S.: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743472/deleting-element-objects-of-a-std-vector-using-erase-a-memory-handling-and-b) but my question here is if it will work on OSX. My remover looks like this:

```
struct Remover : public std::binary_function<CPlayer,void,bool>
{
public:
    bool operator()(const CPlayer &player) const
    {
        return player.IsNewPlayer();
    }
};
```

Comment: Be carefull: `new` is a keyword in C++. You cannot use it as a identifier.

Comment: @Manu343726, yes, I'm. That's why I wrote "Note" in the post. ;-)

Comment: As to the question: I'm not entirely sure I understood what you mean, but `vector` is a generic template, the remove-erase idiom works for any data type it is initialized with. The destructors will be called properly.

Comment: @Manu343726 by the way, this is not related neither to Xcode nor to Visual Studio. It's a question about the C++ language and standard library. (Which, again, is ***not*** the STL. The STL is something entirely different.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. The standard library provides `std::remove`, which removes objects which are equal to some specified value (using the `==` operator), and it has `std::remove_if`, which, instead of a value, takes a function which is called on the object, and if it returns `true`, it indicates that the object should be removed. So simply write a function which defines the condition you want, and use that:

```
players_pool.erase( std::remove_if(
  players_pool.begin(),
  players_pool.end(),
 [](const CPlayer& p){ return p.IsNewPlayer(); }),
 players_pool.end() );
```

Note, I used a lambda for the function passed to `remove_if`. If your compiler doesn't support that yet, you can simply define the function separately, either as a function (with the signature `bool func(const CPlayer&);`, or a function object with an `bool operator()(const CPlayer&)`

Comment: @yalf, will it be supported by the XCode and 10.6 SDK?

Comment: @Igor I don't know, but check my update :) You don't need to use the lambda expression, I just used that to simplify my example

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `std::remove_if` and a lambda function as predicate:

```
players.erase( std::remove_if( players.begin() , 
                               players.end() , 
                               [](const Player& player) { return player.IsNewPlayer(); } 
                              ) );
```

[Lambdas are supported by VC10 (VS2010 C++ compiler).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx)

In XCode you are using Clang? [It supports lambda expressions too.](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html)

On the other hand, if your compiler not supports C++11 lambdas, your functor is the correct way.

Comment: which XCode/SDK starts supporting lambda expression? I'm not sure 10.6 supports them, but I can't be sure it is supported such functor (meaning std::bind2nd).

Comment: Xcode4.4 uses LLVM4.0, wich includes lambdas: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_4.html

Comment: how do I call my functor? "std::bind2nd( Remover() )" gives compiler error "Expect 2 arguments - one provided". Thank you.

Comment: You want to use a unary function, because you want only a function that gets a Player and return a boolean (Check `std::find_if` documentation. The signature of the predicate is very clear). You are using a binary functor. Your `operator()`its fine, but the type of the functor not. Use `std::unary_function` instead: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/unary_function

Comment: @Igor or don't use anything. `std::unary_function` is not required, and in fact is deprecated in C++11.