# Proper implementation of removing vector elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

ALL,

It's continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628459/how-to-remove-an-object-from-stdvector#17628602) thread.

What I tried is to write following code:

```
struct Remover : public std::binary_function<CPlayer,void,bool>
{
public:
    bool operator()(const CPlayer &player) const
    {
        return player.IsNewPlayer();
    }
};
```

and call it this way:

```
players_pool->erase( std::remove_if( players_pool->begin(), players_pool->end(), std::bind2nd( Remover() ) ) );
```

but it gives me an error:

std::bind2nd(): expects 2 arguments - 1 provided.

How do I properly call this functor?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you understand the error message? `expects 2 arguments - 1 provided.` - Also, have you read the documentation of `std::bind2nd()`?

Comment: You need neither `bind2nd` nor `Remover`. Look at `std::mem_fun`.

Comment: @n.m. note that `std::mem_fun` is deprecated. But [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) could be an alternative.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes if you are using C++11, that's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to wrap `Remover()` in `std::bind2nd()`.

Also, you don't need to derive from `std::binary_function<>` (which is wrong, anyway; `Remover` is a unary functor). You don't need to derive from anything, in fact.

Finally, if your compiler supports C++11, you can reduce your code down to this:

```
players_pool->erase( std::remove_if( begin(*players_pool), end(*players_pool),
                                     [](const CPlayer &player) {
                                         return player.IsNewPlayer();
                                     } ),
                     end(*players_pool) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your binary_function to a unary_function.
You also need to add the end iterator to the erase call, in order to erase all removed values.