# How to erase elements in STL vector without copying iterator and without memory leakage?

Tags: c++, memory, vector, stl, iterator

**This is the edited code**

> ```
> vector<vector<int> > vec; 
> vector<vector<int> >::iterator vit; 
> vector<int>::iterator it;
> for ( vit = vec.begin(); vit != vec.end(); ++vit)
> {
>     it = vit->begin();
>     while(it != vit->end()) 
>     {
>         while(it != vit->end())
>         {
>
>             if( condition )
>             {
>                 while( condition )
>                 {
>                     //going back to certain it
>                     //erase an element
>                     it  = vit->erase(it);
>                 }
>             }
>             else
>                 ++it;
>         }
>         ++it;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The inner while loops back to certain point. Link missing.
>   Erasing element without copying iterator and without memory leakage in back loop and again forward?

Comment: `while(it < vit->end())` - This is a bug already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete an element from a vector while looping over it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597240/how-to-delete-an-element-from-a-vector-while-looping-over-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to worry about memory leaks, in your case you use std::vector which uses [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) to make sure no memory is leaked. With STL containers you can "leak" in such case on;y if you do not shrink your vector after using remove algorithm.

Below is fix to your code, and not entire rewrite. This code removes all values equal to 1 [[LIVE]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10e670cd774b1b12):

```
vector<vector<int> > vec = { {0,1,2,3}, {0,1,2,3,4,5}, {0,1} }; 
vector<vector<int> >::iterator vit = vec.begin(); 
vector<int>::iterator it;

while(vit != vec.end()) {
    it = vit->begin();
    while(it != vit->end()) {
     if( *it == 1 ) {
        it = vit->erase(it);

         // Not sure why you want this loop here
         //while( condition )
         //{
         //     **erase an element;**
         //}
     }
     else {
       ++it;
     }
    }
    ++vit;
}  

for (auto it1 = vec.begin(); it1 != vec.end(); ++it1){
    for (auto it2 = it1->begin(); it2 != it1->end(); ++it2)
       std::cout<<*it2<< ", ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

produces:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
0, 2, 3, 
0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
0,
```

Comment: Thanks. The inner 'while' loops back to certain point while going back elements are erased on a condition. There is a problem in going backward and forward again, missing links.

Comment: @RaghuG I probably dont understand, but you can reassign `it` to new iterator, as long as it is in the range of the vector on which it operates. In my example you can assign `it` back to `vit->begin()`, then iterate it again in your inner loop, or better use another iterator.

Comment: Marcin Jędrzejewski Thank you. Solved problem by assigning new iterator.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to remove certain elements of the inner vectors use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) on them:

```
for (auto & intv : vec)
{
  intv.erase( 
    std::remove_if( intv.begin(), intv.end(), 
      [](int value) -> bool { return value == 2; }), 
    intv.end() );
}
```

Notes:

1. You can apply certain conditions depending on `vec` or other local variables by capturing them in the lambda expression.
2. This example would remove all elements from the inner vectors that are equal to `2`.
3. For `int` it is preferable to pass the lambda paramter by value. For bigger objects you'd probably want to have a const reference lambda paramter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) for that purpose.

Simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool is_odd(const int &i)
{
    return (i % 2) != 0;  
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    // removes all odd numbers
    v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), is_odd), v.end());
    for(const auto &i:v)
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Of course you can achieve the same thing using a lambda like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    // removes all odd numbers
    v.erase( std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
        [](const int &i) -> bool {return (i % 2) != 0;}),
        v.end() );
    for(const auto &i:v)
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would be good to include a snippet of code on what the idiom is.

Comment: Completely agree with @Niall. Links tend to break at some point

Comment: You are absolutely right @Niall. I've added a simple example. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use STL vector's erase function. Just use `vector.remove(*it)` to remove the element