# vector loop weird behavior C++

Tags: c++, loops, vector

I'm removing duplicate integers from the vector; the loop I made is working as intended, but only if I add Break; inside the ' if ' statement, or it will give wrong output. Can someone explain why is that happening?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> nums = {3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 6, 6, 3};

int main() 
{

for(int i = nums.size() - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
  for( int z = i - 1; z >= 0; z--) {
    if( nums[i] == nums[z] ) {
    nums.erase(nums.begin() + i);
    break; // if i remove it the resault is wrong
    } 
  }
}
for( int c : nums) {
  cout << c << " "; }
}
```

as it was explained above, break; is needed for  the code but i have no idea why.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Assume i is the index of the last element of your vector (8). Every time you see a 3 you erase an element (at indices 0, 4 and 5) respectively **and shrink the vector**.  Since `i` doesn't decrease along with the vector, you are reading out of bounds, which means that `nums[i]` suddenly means something different.

Comment: use [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) to remove duplicates from a vector. And if this is for an exercise, you can still use `std::unique`, and then look at the possible implementation (same link). Note that the twist is to realize that it is simpler to first rearrange the elements and only then erase the ones you want to get rid of (actually `std::unique` only does the rearranging, same link has a complete example)

Comment: See [How to delete an element from a vector while looping over it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597240/how-to-delete-an-element-from-a-vector-while-looping-over-it)

Comment: you could also replace all occurences of `[]` in your code by a call to `at` to get a more useful diagnostics of whats wrong in your code

Comment: std::unique does not remove duplicate but consecutive duplicate. What does OP needs? First hypothese would give ```{3, 4, 3, 6, 3}``` second one: ```{3, 4, 6}```

Comment: Erasing while looping is a bad idea. If you want a list of unique integers you can use this `std::set<int> unique_values{ nums.begin(), nums.end() };` (@Oersted which is I think your O(n log(n)) complexity)

Comment: sort + std::unique, set is sorting implicitely if I remember correctly and then don't add duplicate. With additionnal constraints on values range you may perform a radix-sort and go down to O(N) again (at the cost of extra memory)

Answer (score 2):

`erase` invalidates locations (and iterators) after erased element and shrinks the vector. As you go "backward" through the vector, it creates an issue, because you decrement `z` while `i` stays same and  finds itself out of bounds or referring same element as `z`... This way you either erase whole vector or would cause a malfunction (undefined behaviour).

THere are ideomatic solutions to this problem which do not involve such convoluted loop. Especially if vector is sorted, this can be done with single standard library call or with a single loop instead of N^2.

Comment: thanks for the information, but im asking why break; is needed inside the if statement
( my code is working fine. )

Comment: @MaamarDarmech that's obvious in light of what I wrote. You exit the innermost loop after erase, allowing decrement of `i` to happen. If you don't, every following comparison is true. (obviously you could play with decreemnts within the loop,but it's even weirder)