# Unusual behaviour with std::list<myclass*>::iterator comparison

Tags: c++, list, visual-c++, iterator

I'm seeing some unusual behavior when I compare two iterators.

```
vector<list<MyClass*>>   vlWatchers(10);
list<MyClass*>::iterator itCurrent, itEnd;

for (int i(0); i <= 9; ++i)
{
    itCurrent = vlWatchers[i].begin();
    itEnd = vlWatchers[i].end();
    while (itCurrent != itEnd)
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

will cause a liste iterators incompatible error on the while() line, and appears to happen when i = 0, although only some of the time.

Upon further investigation after the error is called, itEnd and itCurrent are both equal to 0xcdcdcdcd.  The weird part is when i step into the != compare operator, the "this" pointer BECOMES 0xcdcdcdcd. Shouldn't 0xcdcdcdcd be the **value** that's stored in the iterators, not the **address** of the iterators themselves?  or is there some sort of iterator black magic where the iterator both stores a value and IS the value? This is part of a larger project, but the error is repeatable.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you using a C++0x-compiler? If not, your example has a syntax error in the first line (the double closing brackets of the template).

Comment: Also, can you state which compiler you are using?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: The latest MSVC enables (Microsoft's not-very-complete implementation of) C++0x by default.

Comment: 0xcdcdcdcd means ["uninitialized heap memory"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations), by the way.

Comment: @Paul Are you erasing or deleting the content of the list using iterators?

Comment: @karlphillip quite possibly, this is being used for widgets, and there are way too many going on in the current project.  The solution we had was to make the currentIterator a member variable and increment it on a remove if the what the current iterator was looking at was requested to be removed.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y in the actual code it typedefs list<myclass*>, but i haven't seen any compiler errors about syntax

Comment: I suspect that you might be invalidating iterators because of erase/delete operations. Check this thread to make things safe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645705/vector-erase-iterator/4645727#4645727

Comment: @Marius: That was just MSVC++ not conforming to the standard. Until C++0x, that is not valid, though MSVC++ will accept it.

Comment: @Marius Bancila: what is with other platforms??? Where does Paul tell anything abount MSVC VC++ and more?? Maybe he is on a unix platform, or just uses plain c++, using another compiler, what ever? OK, now he told its VS2005 =)

Comment: Visual Studio 2005 is the compiler

Comment: @billy, @thomas, I read between the lines... I thought it was about VC++

Comment: aha. so it was VC++ after all... I removed the comment though

Comment: Are you trying to debug a **Release** mode executable?  If so, you'll see lots of crazy stuff in the debugger that doesn't make sense.  If that's the case, instead try debugging with the **Debug** build.

Answer (score 0):

Let's follow the logic chain (assuming the first few lines of your `for` loop are exactly as described):

- `itCurrent->this == 0xcdcdcdcd`, therefore ...
- `itCurrent == 0xcdcdcdcd`, therefore ...
- `vlWatchers[i].begin()` returned `0xcdcdcdcd`, therefore ...
- `vlWatchers[i]` is invalid, therefore perhaps ...

  - `i >= vlWatches.size()`, or
  - `vlWatchers` is invalid

I vote for `vlWatchers.size() == 0` somehow. Can you add a check to your method to detect that case?