# Shows an assertion error at runtime in vector c++

Tags: c++, vector, assertion

I want to erase an element from a vector in c++,  but it shows a runtime assertion error.

My code is:

```
   int i=0;
        for(socketIterator=vectClientSocket.begin();socketIterator!=vectClientSocket.end();){
            SOCKET clientSocket=*socketIterator;

            isTrue=getBufferData(strt,stp,rm,clientSocket);
            if(!isTrue){
                vectClientSocket.erase(vectClientSocket.begin()+i);

                vector<RMLObserver*>::iterator it;
                for(it=vectRMLObserver.begin();it<vectRMLObserver.end();it++)
                {
                    RMLObserver *observer = (RMLObserver*)*it;
                    observer->infosetSent(info->getRMLThinTranskportToken());
                }
            }
            else
                ++socketIterator;

            i++;
        }
```

When one element is removed it shows a runtime error,

[image]

Please help me...thank you in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645705/vector-erase-iterator/4645758#4645758

Comment: I suggest you to use while loop instead of for loop 'while( !vec.end())'. Get the first element of the vector and erase it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your iterator after erasing an element:

```
socketIterator = vectClientSocket.erase(socketIterator);
```

see also std::vector<..>::erase(..) [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/)

[EDIT]

Use the operator !=(..) to compare the iterators:

```
for(socketIterator=vectClientSocket.begin();socketIterator!=vectClientSocket.end();){
```

Comment: i change my code and use !=() to compare but still same error.

Comment: @yogesh, you've updated you code with the second fix than Simon said, but you haven't used the first fix he said. The first fix is the one that is really causing your bug. Do it like this `socketIterator = vectClientSocket.erase(socketIterator);`.

Answer (score 1):

After this line:

```
 vectClientSocket.erase(socketIterator);
```

`socketIterator` is an invalid iterator because where it used to point has been erase. Between this line and the next iteration through your loop you never give it a valid value so this line in the next iteration is an invalid dereference.

```
SOCKET clientSocket=*socketIterator;
```

As Simon points out, even before this, the loop condition `socketIterator<vectClientSocket.end()` will also cause undefined behavior as `socketIterator` is no longer a valid iterator into `vectClientSocket`.

Comment: Not only dereferencing the iterator also checking the loop condition is a problem.

Comment: @Simon: Good point. In fact looking at the exact error this is the more likely point at which the assert fires.