# segmentation fault when erasing an object from a vector c++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

So I am seg faulting when I run this function

```
      class vector <Record<value> >::iterator itr = records.begin();

      for (; itr != records.end(); ++itr) {
        if (itr->isSelected()) {
          itr = records.erase(itr);
          recordSize--;
        }
      }
```

where my vector is of `vector <Record <value> > records;` and the function `isSelected()` is just a `boolean` that is either true when the object is selected or false when its not.

Can someone help me please, I don't see the problem with doing it this way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the case where you're deleting the last element, `itr` will first be `records.end()` because that's what `records.erase()` will return, and then you're incrementing it with `++itr`. Try:

```
  while (itr != records.end()) {
    if (itr->isSelected()) {
      itr = records.erase(itr);
      recordSize--;
    } else {
      ++itr;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be erasing vector elements like that, it is not an efficient method as you may cause the reallocation of the vector several times during the process.

The correct and more efficient way of doing this is to use the std::erase function. See [this question for examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector).

Answer (score 1):

`for (; itr != records.end(); ++itr)` is guaranteed not to escape the container and invoke UB if `itr` is not modified in the body of the loop, or if it is decremented.

Here you are advancing the iterator: `itr = records.erase(itr);`.

When you do so, no only you are skipping an element, also you may skip the one-past-the-end imaginary "element", IOW you may **increment past one-past-the-end** (UB).