# How to use remove-erase idiom for removing empty vectors in a vector?

Tags: c++, idioms

I have some trouble with removing a empty vector in a vector using the remove-erase idiom like [Erasing elements from a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector). How can I apply this on:

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours; // want to remove contours.at(i).empty()
contours.erase(remove(contours.begin(), contours.end(), ??? ),contours.end());
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
contours.erase(remove(contours.begin(), contours.end(), vector<Point>()), contours.end());
```

Comment: Indeed: it might be overkill in the sense that the compiler might emit more code than strictly necessary, but it's concise.

Comment: Assuming than the comparison is cheap which it should be, this is a great solution!

Comment: The comparison should be cheap as the first thing `vector::operator==` does is to compare size() for both sides.

Comment: Blastfurnace thought that should be the case.

Answer (score 5):

Use `remove_if` that takes a predicate.

```
contours.erase(
    std::remove_if(
         contours.begin(), contours.end(),
         [](const vector<Point>& v) { return v.empty(); }
         // or a functor/plain function/Boost.Lambda expression
    ), contours.end()
);
```

Comment: It's works! Nice suggestion, I actually looked at during it with lambda expressions, so thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Although everybody likes lambdas, I find `std::mem_fn(&std::vector<Point>::empty)` even more concise and clear.

Answer (score 2):

use remove_if.

C++11

```
contours.erase(
    std::remove_if(contours.begin(), contours.end(), 
        [&](const Vector<Point>& vp){
            return vp.empty();
        }),
        contours.end());
```

C++03

```
struct is_empty
{
    bool operator()(const Vector<Point>& vp) constt;
    {
        return vp.empty();
    }
}


contours.erase(
         std::remove_if(contours.begin(), contours.end(), 
         is_empty,
         contours.end());
```

Comment: You don't need a custom functor in C++03, a simple `std::mem_fun_ref(&std::vector<Point>::empty)` should suffice.

Comment: The same holds for C++11, just with `std::mem_fn`, where it's also more concise and conceptually cleaner than a lambda, but Ok, that is maybe rather a matter of taste. But for C++03, not using its scarce functional facilities when they finally make perfect sense is a little bit of a crime ;)

Comment: By the way, it should be `const` istead of `constt` and `is_empty()` instead of just `is_empty` inside the function call.