# What happens to the element when remove_if is used?

Tags: c++, erase-remove-idiom

I'm trying to understand how `remove_if` works (the `<<` is overloaded) and for that I want to remove_if all the strings which begin with 'C':

```
vector<string> langs = { "Python", "C++", "C", "Java", "C#" };
cout << "Initial vector: " << langs << " | Size = " << langs.size() << endl;
```

**Output**: `Initial vector: Python C++ C Java C#  | Size = 5`

Then I write:

```
auto it = remove_if(begin(langs), end(langs), [](const string& s) 
                                              { return s[0]== 'C';});
cout << "After remove_if: " << langs << " | Size = " << langs.size() << endl;
```

**Output 2**: `After remove_if: Python Java C  C#  | Size = 5`

**What I understand**: elements that should remain are removed to the beginning and the `*it` now equals `"C"`

**Question**: What happens to `"C++"`? If `"Java"` replaced it, why

```
for(auto& _it = it; _it != end(langs); _it++)
    cout << *_it << " ";
```

gives **Output 3**: `C  C#` and not `"C", "Java", "C#"`?

Comment: Post a [MCVE] along with a description of the intended output and the actual output.

Comment: Are you asking how elements get removed from a vector? It’s by shifting every element after them over.

Comment: [Using `erase`-`remove_if` idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39019806/335858)

Comment: I am reminded of an old Dilbert cartoon.  Do you have a telephone book? Get one. Put it in your chair and stand on it. Yell out, "Can anyone here read documentation?" http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/  :-)

Comment: @JiveDadson What makes you think I didn't read it? Actually I did write the I-understand part to show that I did. My question was what happens to the element physically and why the size remains the same even though we can't see the element in the output.

Comment: Read it again. It explains exactly what happens to the "removed" object, which depends on whether the compiler is C++98 or C++11 and later. It's all there.

Comment: It [moves](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment) the "next" item, to the place which has the place to be removed,   so in your case, it moved "C, Java, C#", to the place of "C++", then moved "Java, C#" to place of "C++",   so the valid is "Python Java", but your result are due to that the vector still have some old values (invalid)

Comment: Always remember that `remove` and `remove_if` do not remove anything from the container. They just rearrange it so that `erase` can be used to zap the elements off of the end of the container (which removes them).

Comment: It is all explained in [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).

Comment: why they named `remove` and `remove_if` methods that don't remove anything but actually move objects around is the real mistery to me. Anyone can give a reference about such strange choice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::remove\_if not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729906/stdremove-if-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 0):

`remove_if` is basically a variation of `copy_if` where the destination overwrites the source, and the sense of the predicate is reversed, along with an optimization that it doesn't actually copy the leading elements if they're not moving.  It also uses moves instead of copies, if that is relevant.

So all `remove_if` really does is move down (towards the front) elements for which the predicate is false.  It doesn't touch those 'left over' elements, so they'll still be there and you need to call `erase` with the return value of `remove_if` if you want to get rid of them.