# C++ Removing elements from concurrent vectors

Tags: c++, tbb

i am building a network intrusion detection system using visual c++ and one of its component is a tcp session manager for the whole network. The tcp session data is stored in a concurrent vector so that it can be accessed from other threads. I found out there is no easy way to remove a session from the concurrent vector once the session is closed. So my QUESTION is what is the smartest method you know of for removing items from concurrent vectors.

Smart == fairly easy to program without too much performance hit
Thankyou

Comment: Have a look at [Erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom). Not sure if it is helpful for concurrent vectors but for vectors in general.

Comment: take a look at this stack overflow answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector

Comment: What is a "*concurrent vector*"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he means this [concurrent vector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee355343.aspx).

Comment: @Rob and Karl, i am using concurrent_vector from intel's thread building library [www.threadingbuildingblocks.org](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider using a `std::set` instead of a vector here - especially if the number of items stored is large.  I imagine you'll also want to perform lookups frequently.

Search and removal from the set is `O(log(n))` complexity rather than `O(n)` for the `std::vector` - although the trivial insertion case in the is `O(1)` rather than `O(log(n))` with the set.

You will also need mutex to protect all of these operations.