# What index to use in going through vectors

Tags: c++, oop, memory-management, vector, indexing

OK, I'd like to clear something once and for all. If I have a normal vector, like:

```
std::vector<Object*> coll;
```

and I want to go through its elements, I know three ways to go about it:

**1.** Using `int` index, such as: `for(int i = 0; i < coll.size(); ++i)`

**2.** Using `type_t` index, same as 1.: `for(size_t i = 0; i < coll.size(); ++i)`

and access elements in both 1 and 2 by: `coll[i]`

or

**3.** Using `const_iterator`, as in:

```
std::vector<Object*>::const_iterator i;
for(i = coll.begin(); i != coll.end(); ++i)
       // stuff
```

and access elements with `*it`.

I've noticed (and heard) that the third way is the most fail-proof one, but it's quite unpleasant when it comes to deallocating the vector, because when I use `const_iterator`, if I do something like `delete (*it)`, or even `coll.erase(it)` before deallocating, my iterator loses its value, and then I can't continue with the `for` loop.

What's the suggested/good way to do this?

Comment: In C++11 you have a fourth way: `for (Object* obj : coll) ... `

Comment: You might also want to consider [for_each](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) *et al*.

Comment: Also, doing e.g. `delete *it` in the third case doesn't actually invalidate the _iterator_, only what it "points" to.

Comment: `delete(*it)` shouldn't invalidate your iterator (although it probably means that your doing something else wrong). Can you expand with details about the actual problem that you are facing?

Comment: #5: `std::for_each(coll.begin(), coll.end(), [](){ ... });`

Comment: How about 5-th method vector<T>::reverse_iterator rit;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first two approaches are both not entirely correct. The correct index type is

```
std::vector<Object*>::size_type
```

This is what [size()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) returns, and it is what [operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) takes.

The approach using iterators is the idiomatic one. You wrote

> when I use const_iterator, if I do something like delete (*it), or even coll.erase(it) before deallocating, my iterator loses its value, and then I can't continue with the for loop

This is not correct. In something like

```
// ..
std::vector<int *>::const_iterator it, end = v.end();
for ( it = v.begin(); it != end; ++it ) {
    delete *it;
}
```

You don't invalidate the iterator `it`. You merely call `delete` on what the iterator points to. So you can safely advance the iterator after the `delete`.

Comment: Ah ok great, but lets say I go through a vector with ints, and want to erase all odd elements, how can I retain the value of the iterator and still erase the element? f.e. `for(...) if((*it)%2) coll.erase(it)` invalidates the iterator :)

Comment: Then you should use `erase_if` anyway.

Comment: And also, if I use `size_type`, can I be sure that it will work 100%, as long as I don't change the <vector> container?

Comment: @Vidak: Regarding your first question - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector for how to erase elements from a vector. Regarding your question about `size_type`: yes, you can rely on it. In fact, the type is even available for other containers.

Answer (score 1):

`#3` one is more generic one and it makes your code more flexible.
If at some point of time you need to change your standard library container from `std::vector` to some other container then `#3` will work for any of the other containers as is.(*Notice the use of `!=` instead of `<` or `>`*)

Comment: However, if you need to change your container chances are that you *don't* want your existing code compile as it is - "beware the illusion of container independant code", as Scott Meyers put it in Item 2 of "Effective STL". If you change your container, you probably have to take much more into account.

Answer (score 1):

size_t is the correct type in general to use to index into an array as it's basically defined to be a type that's big enough to hold the largest size of an object. It's really defined to be the size of a memory range but is also the best type to hold an array index so that you know it will be large enough.

On a 64 bit system you might be able to have arrays that fill hundreds of GB of memory but int can only hold numbers up to 2billion or so whereas size_t should be an appropriate type to index any array the system can cope with.

Comment: So for normal arrays, created with `[]` or dynamically, I should always use `size_t` instead of int index? Is this memory-inefficient for smaller programs and small objects?

Comment: size_t will usually be defined to be the same as unsigned int so it's exactly the same. The difference is that your code will be portable to platforms where that might be wrong

Comment: The correct type is the one which `operator[]` expects; since Vidak is using a `std::vector` (as opposed to a raw array), this would be `std::vector::size_type` (which is probably usually an alias for `size_t`, but still).

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> ...or even coll.erase(it) before deallocating, my iterator loses its
>   value, and then I can't continue with the for loop...

`vector::erase` returns an iterator to the next valid element in a collection.
Therefore you can write:

```
std::vector<Object*>::const_iterator i;
for(i = coll.begin(); i != coll.end(); )
{
  i = coll.erase(i);
}
```

Note that you must not increment `i` in that case (`i++`).

Comment: yes but I want to increment `i` in most cases, because I need to remove more than one element...