# Erase list element from unordered_set

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, linked-list, openmp

I have a `list<pair<int , double>> lSeedList` and an `unordered_set<int> sToDelete`. I want to remove the pairs in the list that have their first member equal to an int in sToDelete. Currently I am using the following code :

```
void updateSL(list<pair<int, double> >& lSeedList, const unordered_set<int>& sAddedFacets)
{
    list<pair<int, double> >::iterator it = lSeedList.begin();
    while(it != lSeedList.end())
    {
        if(sAddedFacets.count(it->first) != 0)
            it = lSeedList.erase(it);
        else
            ++it;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to speed up this code ? Is it possible to efficiently parallelize it with OpenMP (dividing the list in each thread and then merging them with splice) ?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 under Windows 7. The size of lSeedList is ~1 million at the start and the size of sToDelete is ~10000. The int in the pair acts like an unique ID.

Comment: You should look into the [`erase`-`remove` idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector), which is essentially what you're shooting for.

Comment: @Cyril See my updated post. At first it has a typo in the lambda expression.:)

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use either standard algorithm `std::remove_if`

For exameple

```
lSeedList.erase( std::remove_if( lSeedList.begin(), lSeedList.end(),
                                 [&]( const std::pair<int, double> &p )
                                 {
                                     return sAddedFacets.count( p.first );
                                 } ),
                                 lSeedList.end() );
```

Or member function `remove_if` of class `std::list`

For example

```
lSeedList.remove_if( [&]( const std::pair<int, double> &p )
                     {
                         return sAddedFacets.count( p.first );
                     } );
```

Comment: I implemented the second option with a struct, and believe it or not my bit of code is apparently slightly faster :) I am going to try another methods using a boolean vector. Thanks for the help !