# C++ suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value

Tags: c++, codeblocks, compiler-warnings, objective-c++

I have some problems with this part of my code:

**Employees.cpp**:

```
void Employees::delete_employee()
{
    int employee_number;

    cout<<"\n..."<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Give me the number:";
    cin>>Employee_number;

    for(std::vector<EmployeeStruct>::size_type i = 0; i != lista.size(); i++)
        {
            if (employee_number = lista[i].Employee_number)
            {
                lista.erase(lista.begin() + i);
            }
        }
    cout<<"..."<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"--------------------------------"<<endl;

}
```

When I compile my code I see something like that: *warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]* and I really don't know what to do with that. Maybe it isn't a serious problem, but my program doesn't work like I want. (this code should delete employee)

In **main.cpp** I have:

```
    case 4:
        {
            Pracownicy p;
            p.usun_pracownika();
        }
    break;
```

Maybe somebody can help me.

Comment: You want `employee_number == lista[i].Employee_number`. Notice ***assignment used as truth value***.

Comment: Use [Erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) to fix your other error.

Comment: ... or *don't* increment `i` after you've just erased an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm realy don't know what to do with that.

It depends on what you intended to do.

If you didn't intend to assign, but rather, compare equality, then you should fix the code to use the equality operator: `==`

If you did intend to assign, then you can: a) Ignore the warning or b) add the parentheses which tells the compiler that you really intend to do an assignment and that it was not a mistake. Or as commented by Christian Hackl c) Split assignment and comparison into two statements for increased readability.

There is also another bug in your code. The erase shifts the rest of the elements left. The next element is no longer at `i++`, so you end up skipping elements after an erase. This is also inefficient if more than one element is erased. See [erase-remove idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/347445/2079303) for a better way.

Comment: c) Split assignment and comparison into two statements for increased readability.

Comment: It's clear from the code that comparison was intended. I think instead of " erase invalidates the erase" you *meant* "the erase invalidates iterators and references after the erased item", which, after think about it, you would realize doesn't matter, but that possibly skipping over the end matters. Apart from skipping over the end (bug) it' just an inefficient, quadratic time, way of removing items.

Comment: Yes, but there's no iterator here. It's plain indexing. ;-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf wow, totally true. I must have glanced over the code too fast. Removed iterator stuff from the answer now.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf  It might be clear that comparison was intended, but someone might stumble upon this question about the warning having actually done the assignment on purpose, so that's to make my answer more general.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is this very common error:

```
if (employee_number == lista[i].Employee_number)
                    ^^
{
     lista.erase(lista.begin() + i);
}
```

You have confused the boolean check `==` operator for the `=` assignment operator here, either as a typo or by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm realy don't know what to do with that.

Use a equals comparison instead of the assignment, that's what the warning finally suggests in most cases:

```
 if (employee_number == lista[i].Employee_number)
                  // ^^
```

or make it clear what you want using parenthesis around

```
if ((employee_number = lista[i].Employee_number))
```

Not of such a good warning of the compiler though.

Answer (score 0):

A simple mistake. You wrote:

```
 if (employee_number = lista[i].Employee_number)
```

write

```
if (employee_number == lista[i].Employee_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem on your side is inadvertent use of the assignment operator `=` instead of the intended comparison `==`.

On the language's side this common problem was enabled via two risk-enhancing features inherited from original C, namely that a formal *condition* accepts any object with a conversion to `bool`, and that, in support of multi-assignments, assignment is an expression rather than a statement.

You were lucky to compile with a compiler and options that produced a *warning* about it: such warnings are not guaranteed.

---

A guaranteed way to instead get an *error* is to let the left hand side be an expression that can't be assigned to, e.g.

- use `const` liberally, wherever it makes sense.

In the given case, instead of

```
void Employees::delete_employee()
{
    int employee_number;

    cout<<"\n..."<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Give me the number:";
    cin>>Employee_number;

    for(std::vector<EmployeeStruct>::size_type i = 0; i != lista.size(); i++)
        {
            if (employee_number = lista[i].Employee_number)
            {
                lista.erase(lista.begin() + i);
            }
        }
    cout<<"..."<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"--------------------------------"<<endl;

}
```

you can do the safer

```
auto fail() -> bool ...;

auto line_from( istream& stream )
    -> string
{
    string line;
    getline( stream, line )
        or fail();
    return line;
}

void Employees::delete_employee()
{
    cout<<"\n..."<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Give me the number:";
    int const Employee_number = to_string( line_from( cin ) );

    for(std::vector<EmployeeStruct>::size_type i = 0; i != lista.size(); i++)
        {
            if (employee_number == lista[i].Employee_number)
            {
                lista.erase(lista.begin() + i);
            }
        }
    cout<<"..."<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"--------------------------------"<<endl;

}
```

This code will not compile at all if `==` is used instead of `=`, and as a bonus using `getline` helps to avoid many common problems with input of values from `cin`.

---

A different kind of fix is to redefine `if` via a macro, or to define a macro that expands to a safe use of `if`. The first is technically possible but formally Undefined Behavior if any standard library header is included, which is usually the case. The second is a severe (usually unacceptable) uglification of the code, and will make maintenance a nightmare. As I recall something like that was once done for one of the Unix shells. Since nobody but the original programmer understood any of the code, it had a short life.