# vector iterator not incrementable, which is related to the operation of iterator and erase

Tags: c++

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to solve this problem.

```
class Solution{
public:
    int removeElement(vector<int> &nums, int val)
    {

        for (auto &it = nums.begin(); it != nums.end(); ++it)
        {
            if (*it == val)
            {
                it = nums.erase(it);
            }
        }
        return nums.size();
    }
};
int main(void)
{
    Solution s; 
    vector<int> vi = { 3, 2, 2, 3 };
    cout << "size = " << s.removeElement(vi, 3) << endl;
    for (auto &i : vi)
    {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

which are the class body and main function body of my code.
But when i run it, compiler popped a window:

[image]

Comment: That's not the compiler showing an error, that is your program *crashing*.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks for pointing out my mistake

Comment: By the way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/347478/440119 -- It's not only convenient, it's more runtime efficient than your method.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Thanks for your guide. Those answers of that question wide my mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After erasing the last element, `it` becomes `nums.end()` and incrementing it is not allowed.

You shouldn't increment `it` after erasing. This will also fix problem that one element is skipped after erasure.

Also the `&` in `auto &it = nums.begin()` should be removed because having it will make it invalid initialization of non-const reference.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Solution{
public:
    int removeElement(vector<int> &nums, int val)
    {

        for (auto it = nums.begin(); it != nums.end();)
        {
            if (*it == val)
            {
                it = nums.erase(it);
            } else
            {
                ++it;
            }
        }
        return nums.size();
    }
};
int main(void)
{
    Solution s; 
    vector<int> vi = { 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3 }; // added testcase of consecutive 3
    cout << "size = " << s.removeElement(vi, 3) << endl;
    for (auto &i : vi)
    {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Now I understand the reason why my program crashed.