# remove upper letters from list and write it into another list

Tags: c++, list, lambda, erase

I must create a string list and remove upper letters with lambda and write it into another list, so i try but i have  bug:`[Error] request for member 'erase' in 'c', which is of non-class type 'const char'`

```
list<string> ls {"hak","ala","alA","coS","KtOs"};
list<string> ls2;
for(auto k : ls)cout<<k<<endl<<endl;
transform(ls.begin(),ls.end(),ls.begin(),[](string &s) {    
             transform(s.begin(),s.end(),s.begin(), [](const char& c) { 
                  if(isupper(c) );return c.erase(isupper(c)) ; 
               });
          return s;
```

Comment: When you have *some* bugs, you need to apply *some* fixes.

Comment: i have one bug :[Error] request for member 'erase' in 'c', which is of non-class type 'const char'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lambda of yours:

```
[](const char& c) { 
     if(isupper(c) );
          return c.erase(isupper(c)) ; 
}
```

You have a `;` in your `if`... effectively translating it to a dead code...
And `c` is of type `char`, it has no members. WHat are you even trying to do? `isupper` returns a non zero value (meaning it could be anything) to signify `true`.

I presume what you want to do is:

```
transform(ls.begin(), ls.end(), back_inserter(ls2),
            [](string s) -> string
            {
                s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(),
                           [](char c){
                                  return isupper(c);
                           }), s.end()
                       );
                    return s;
             });
```

Again, I used `back_inserter` for the new list because its assumed it doesn't contain any element yet. The other is [Remove/Erase Idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/347478/1621391). And please see the documentation of [`isupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper).

Full example here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4df3c806d7d35de4

Comment: Thanks, you are very helpful.