# Work with arrays (string) C

Tags: c++, arrays, string

This is a beta test code of the algorithm Malgrange, I need to create array Y1 from C0... (Y1 = C0 - X0)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
// create array C0
string** masiv_C0=new string*[3];

for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    masiv_C0[i]=new string [2];

masiv_C0[0][0]="AB";
masiv_C0[0][1]="C";

masiv_C0[1][0]="X";
masiv_C0[1][1]="Z";

masiv_C0[2][0]="XY";
masiv_C0[2][1]="ZQ";

//create array X0 
string** masiv_X0=new string*[1];
masiv_X0[i]=new string [2];

masiv_X0[0][0]="X";
masiv_X0[0][1]="Z";

//create array Y1 = C0 - X0 (remove from C0 elements X0)
bool flag;
string** masiv_Y1=new string*[3];

for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    masiv_Y1[i]=new string [2];

for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    flag=true;
    for (int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        if ((masiv_C0[i][0]==masiv_X0[j][0])&&(masiv_C0[i][1]==masiv_X0[j][1]))
        {
            flag=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag)
    {
        masiv_Y1[i][0]=masiv_C0[i][0];
        masiv_Y1[i][1]=masiv_C0[i][0];
    }
}

for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<2;j++)
    {
        cout<<masiv_Y1[i][j];
    }
    cout<<endl<<endl;
}}
```

Of course the algorithm is not finalized and most of the code is not here, but the problem is this error, I can not create an array without the elements that are contained in a subset of the other elements

Comment: Do yourself a favor and learn how to use the STL container classes instead of raw arrays and pointers.

Comment: "`std::string** masiv_c0 = new std::string*[3]`" - don't use dynamically allocated C-arrays. If you want to have a matrix of `std::string` instances then use `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` and save yourself a big headache whilst doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you posted what the proper output should be, it would have been helpful.

However, given your description, it would be better served if you used STL container and algorithms to do any sort of removal of elements, since arrays cannot be resized.  For example, the `std::vector` class serves as a dynamic array of elements.

Your code attempts to "resize" the array by writing over previous elements, which is not necessary when using `std::vector`, since using `vector`, you will actually be removing elements, not just merely writing over items in the array.

Here is an implementation of your code that uses `std::vector`, and a few STL algorithms to do the work (again, I am going by your description in your post):

First we use the requisite headers:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
```

Next, we create some `typedefs` for convenience.

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> String1D;  // a 1 dimensional "array" of string
typedef std::vector<String1D> String2D;  // a 2 dimensional "array" of string
```

Now that we have the above, it is really simple to create the two-dimensional arrays, all without using `new[]`:

```
int main()
{
    // create array C0
    String2D masiv_C0(3, String1D(2));
    masiv_C0[0][0]="AB";
    masiv_C0[0][1]="C";
    masiv_C0[1][0]="X";
    masiv_C0[1][1]="Z";
    masiv_C0[2][0]="XY";
    masiv_C0[2][1]="ZQ";

    //create array X0 
    String2D masiv_X0(1, String1D(2));
    masiv_X0[0][0]="X";
    masiv_X0[0][1]="Z";
```

Next, we simply create a "Y" 2-dimensional array by first starting out with the masiv_C0 array:

```
String2D masiv_Y1 = masiv_C0;
```

Once we have that, then we can remove the elements from `masiv_Y1` easily using a loop and using [erase / remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector) idiom:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < masiv_X0.size(); ++i)
{
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < masiv_X0[i].size(); ++j)
    {
        auto& str = masiv_X0[i][j];
        for (size_t cur = 0; cur < masiv_Y1.size(); ++cur)
        {
            auto iter = std::remove(masiv_Y1[cur].begin(), masiv_Y1[cur].end(), str);
            masiv_Y1[cur].erase(iter, masiv_Y1[cur].end());
        }
    }
}
```

So basically, for each string in the `masiv_X0` array, we go through each row of the `masiv_Y` array, searching and removing the `masiv_X0` string.  This is accomplished by using the `std::remove` function, and then to rid the array of the elements, the `vector::erase` function is used.

[Here is a live example](http://ideone.com/tst4fB)

Note how we also output the final results in the example.  The `size()` member function is used instead of hard-coding the number of rows and columns.

Comment: @Merk30 You need to fix your compiler that CodeBlocks is using.  CodeBlocks is an IDE, not a compiler.  You may be using a very old version of g++.  Also, "Linux" is not a C++ compiler, it is an operating system.  Basically you need to properly know and identify the tools that you're using, number one being the exact compiler and version you're using to build your code.  The code compiles without error using Visual Studio 2015, and various versions of g++ and clang [as seen here](http://rextester.com/VQTWZ20327)

Comment: It seems you forgot `#include <algorithm>`.  Second [here is your code using `std::vector`](http://ideone.com/C2Hed6).