# How to convert functionbody into lambda?

Tags: c++

I want to convert a function body into a lambda. But I don't know how you can implement this if statement into the lambda. I also dont know what is the best to use for this. Is it better to use std::find_if, std::find or something else.

```
void Inventory::RemoveFromInventory(std::string  item)
{
    //--bool to check if an item is in the inventory
    bool found = false;

    for (std::list<Item>::iterator i = m_Inventory.begin(); i != m_Inventory.end(); i++)
    {
        if (i->GetName() == item)
        {
            m_Inventory.erase(i);
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found == false)
    {
        std::cout << "item not in inventory!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Cann someone help me with this conversion problem?

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you want to do that? afaik lambdas are mainly syntactic sugar for functors, but if you already have written down the method, what do you gain?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector

Comment: this for a school assignment, we need to implemt lambda's as much as possible. Is this possible for thsi function?

Comment: ...or do you maybe want to transform the for-loop into a `find_if`? I guess yes, also the answer given uses that interpretation...

Comment: @Caleth please dont answer questions in comment. Anyhow your comment is same as the solution proposed in an already given answer

Answer (score 3):

So you want to search for an item that verifies a condition, check whether you found it, and erase it. That's a use case for `std::find_if`:

```
void Inventory::RemoveFromInventory(std::string item)
{
    auto const foundAt = std::find_if(
        begin(m_Inventory),
        end(m_Inventory),
        [&](Item const &i) { return i.GetName() == item; }
    );

    if(foundAt == end(m_Inventory)) {
        std::cout << "item not in inventory!\n";
    } else {
        m_Inventory.erase(foundAt);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Gruffalo `begin` and `end` are found by ADL. `find_if` is, too, but I personally prefer qualifying it.

Comment: Shouldn't I add `using std::begin` and `using std::end` to make sure ADL works correctly?

Comment: @EmeraldWeapon `using std::begin; begin(a);` is only needed when you need to support the case where `a` is a C-style array.

Comment: How does `begin(m_Inventory)` resolve to `std::begin(m_Inventory)` in your example if `m_Inventory` is not in `std` namespace?

Comment: @EmeraldWeapon the *type* of `m_Inventory`, `std::list`, is what matters :)

Comment: I was missing that part, thanks for the clarification.