# STL container to use for deleting a range of values

Tags: c++, stl

I have with myself `n` integers. I am given with `starting value(SV)` and `ending value(EV)`, I need to delete the values that lie within the range of these values. The starting value as well the ending value may not exist in the set of n integers. This I need to do in `O(No. Of elements deleted)`. Container such as `vector` of integers is failing since I need to B.Search and get the iterator that is greater than equal to the `SV` and for `EV` as well which takes an additional time of `Log n`. Any approach appreciated.

Edit : I was even thinking of using maps, storing the values as keys, and erasing on the basis of those key values. But the problem again is that the operation `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` occur in `log` time.

Comment: "Adds a factor of Log N" is rather confusing. A "factor" usually refers to a multiplier. In this case, it's not a multiplication. You have `O(N) + O(log N) + O(log N)` which is just `O(N)`. (Since O(log N) is a subset of O(N) and 3*O(N) is still O(N)). On a c++ note, what's wrong with `std::set<int>` ?

Comment: @MSalters corrected it.

Comment: Assuming you use an already sorted data structure, you won't be able to delete your elemens in `O(No. of elements deleted)` since already searching for an element in a sorted datastructure needs in general `log(N)` where N is the number of elements in the datastructure.

The best you can achieve is `O(No. of elements deleted + log(N))`

Comment: @Akash, with std::set the compexity will be `O(No. of elements deleted + logN)`. It's not a factor.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how ! @DAle

Comment: @Akash, you'll find two iterators (your range) with `lower_bound` in `O(logN)` and then erase all elements in that range with `erase` in `O(No of elements deleted)`

Comment: @DAle Oh yes, but my problem is if I repeat this operation a certain number of times, the `log n` becomes a factor, while the number of elements deleted becomes O(n), n = no. of elements deleted. I want the latter. No `log n` factor.

Comment: When assigning `O` complexity only the largest factor is considered. Erasing `n` elements should dominate a binary search to find the elements to erase.

Comment: @Galik Suppose each time I delete only `1` element and repeat the operation `n` no. of times, then the time for delete is `O(n)` and searching adds each time overhead of `log n` , i.e. total of `O(nlogn)`, hence `O(nlogn)` dominates in the case, and not the erasing part.

Comment: @Akash, I don't think you could get rid of logarithmic search operations if you don't have any details that you didn't tell us. May be you have some restrictions on numbers or delete operations?

Comment: Seems like it. Thanks anyways !

Comment: @Galik: True, but we have two different variables here: container size and erase size. If the container size is much, much larger than the erase size, even log(container size) > erase size. In particular, Akash suggests that the erase size can be as small as 1.

Comment: Even with a full space over time tradeoff (`std::vector<bool>`), you only get O(1) searching of elements, but erasure now is O(EV-SV).

Comment: Is this about Standard Template Library of C++ Standard Library? I know the term STL is used ambiguously.

Comment: Given that the container size and number to erase size are unknown then we can assume that *on average* the erase size would be half the container size all things being random.

Comment: But with that you cant formulate O() time bounds @Galik

Comment: @Akash You can usually contrive a *worst case scenario* for an algorithm. But you have to take the unknwn as completely random unless you have more details to add to the problem

Comment: You can provide an *amortized* `O` value

Comment: Ya thats ok, but I require O() time bounds and must inlcude in it worst case. :( @Galik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need keep order in container just use:
`set` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/
or `multiset` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/multiset/ if values can repeat.

Both have `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [erase-remove idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector) with [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) to check if each value is between the two bounds.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int start = 3;
    int stop = 7;
    values.erase(std::remove_if(values.begin(),
                                values.end(),
                                [start, stop](int i){ return i > start && i < stop; }),
                 values.end());
    for (auto i : values)
    {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
}
```

[Output](http://cpp.sh/7yv6s)

```
1 2 3 7 8 9
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the functioning of this and the time complexity.

Comment: The erase-remove idiom is O(N) in time complexity, where N is the original number of elements in the container. This is because you must compare every element against your predicate (in this case, if the number is outside the allowable bounds)

Comment: But I want my algo to be `O(no of elements deleted)` and not `O(N)`,`N` being no of elements in container.

Answer (score 0):

As Marek R suggested there is `std::multiset`.

Complexity of the whole exercise is O(log(values.size()+std::distance(first,last)) where that distance is 'number of elements erased'.

It's difficult to see how you can beat that. At the end of it there is always going to be something that increases with the size of the container and log of it is a good deal!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

void dump(const std::multiset<int>& values);

int main() {
    std::multiset<int> values;
    values.insert(5);
    values.insert(7);

    values.insert(9);
    values.insert(11);
    values.insert(8);
    values.insert(8);
    values.insert(76);

    dump(values);
    auto first=values.lower_bound(7);
    auto last=values.upper_bound(10);    
    values.erase(first,last);
    dump(values);

    return 0;
}

void dump(const std::multiset<int>& values){
    auto flag=false;
    std::cout<<'{';
    for(auto curr : values){
        if(flag){
            std::cout<<',';
        }else{
            flag=true;
        }
        std::cout<< curr;
    }
    std::cout<<'}'<<std::endl;
}
```