# Deleting objects in vector C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have the following problem:

```
    vector<CPerson>toRemove;// has some objects that are contained in m_vObjects
    vector<CPerson>m_vObjects;

    for (auto it = toRemove.begin(); it != toRemove.end(); ++it)
    {
        for (auto iter = m_vObjects.begin(); iter != m_vObjects.end(); ++iter)
        {
            iter = m_vObjects.erase(it);
        }

    }
```

What I want to do is delete all the objects from `m_vObjects` that are contained in `toRemove`. I have tried a lot of stuff, but nothing worked fine.

Comment: erase(remove_if(...remainder left blank as an exercise ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Erasing elements from a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong: you cannot use iterator from one container to remove items from the other container. One way to achieve what you want is to use [`std::set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) (requires your arrays to be sorted):

```
vector<CPerson>toRemove;// has some objects that are contained in m_vObjects
vector<CPerson>m_vObjects;

vector<int> diff;

std::set_difference(
    m_vObjects.begin(), m_vObjects.end(), 
    v2.begin(), v2.end(), 
    std::inserter(diff, diff.begin()));

m_objects = diff;
```

If it is not desired to sort arrays, then you can use [`std::remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove):

```
for (const auto& element_to_remove : toRemove) {
    std::remove (
        m_vObjects.begin (),
        m_vObjects.end (),
        element_to_remove);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to mention, that `std::set_difference` works on **sorted** ranges. So, if the vectors, that OP uses, are not sorted, your suggestion invokes UB.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, you are right, I shall fix my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1) You cannot use iterator from toRemove in m_vObjects. They are strongly connected to each instance of collection.

2) It is not really a good practice to use loop on iterators while modifying collection: for example you have deleted an object after current interator, but he still thinks that object is there. If I'm correct, it causes undefined behavior.

3) The fix should be check equality of objects, that are pointed by iterators.

```
  if( ( *it == *iter )
  {
     iter= vObjects.erase( iter );
  }
```

But still, my solution works only if == is overloaded for person, or you have another method that checks equality. And it is very bad for performance. Actually, IMHO, such actions at vectors are always bad for performance, it's better to use set or map if you need to find something. And set has some in-build methods to intersect them.

Comment: Your "solution" invokes UB, because `innerIt` is invalidated at `vObjects.erase( innerIt );` call.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius lol, yes, I explained that it's bad and used it myself. Thanks that payed attention, fixed

Comment: 1) Hint: [`std::vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) Returns "_Iterator following the last removed element._". 2) If `m_vObjects` contains multiple identical objects - your updated solution won't remove them all.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I knew about problem with multiple object, but before your hint had no ideas how to deal with it.