# What is return value from std::vector erase operator, according to the standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, syntax, language-lawyer

I prefer to get info from the source, for this case this is ISO-IEC 14882,
where erase method is described as the following:

> "iterator erase(const_iterator position);
> iterator erase(const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
>
> Effects: Invalidates
> iterators and references at or after the point of the erase.
>
> Complexity: The destructor of T is called the number of times equal to
> the number of the elements erased, but the move assignment operator of
> T is called the number of times equal to the number of elements in the
> vector after the erased elements.
>
> Throws: Nothing unless an exception
> is thrown by the copy constructor, move constructor, assignment
> operator, or move assignment operator of T."

Can't find information about returned iterator,
of course, I Googled and got:

> An iterator pointing to the new location of the element that followed
> the last element erased by the function call

Can't understand there this is described in the standard
Could you point me on it?

**Update:** my question is not about how `vector::erase` works,
but rather from where in the standard, as I accept as reliable source of information we can deduce information about returned value

Comment: Anything particular you didn't get from the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)?

Comment: I strongly recommend not using the standard as reference documentation. Only use it when you need to be a language lawyer. [cppreference has good C++ reference documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you take for granted anything that is put on the internet? ))

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector

Comment: @Justin Actually, I think the text the OP provided is slightly clearer than that of cppreference, in this case. Anyway, they are semantically identical.

Comment: @spin_eight I don't know anything about your google fu, but that documentation is granted to be at the internet, yes :). If you have doubts about the standard conformance tag your question [tag:language-lawyer] please.

Comment: @spin_eight cppreference is a well known, high quality reference site. It is trustworthy unless proven otherwise.

Comment: @spin_eight cppreference.com is a pretty reliable and well known source. Trusting it is very different from trusting "anything that is put on the internet". I've found more compiler bugs than errors in cppreference.com

Comment: What you Googled is correct. The desire to find it in the standard is not.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz why not? The standard is an official document, that describes the language. Could you please elaborate on your comment?

Comment: @spin_eight People typically don't pay 100s of dollars for every ISO that comes out over the years in order to look up the return type of a method. Also, the standard is not written to be a reference for every method on every stl type, it's written to be the language standard. Just type the method name into google with "C++" and read the results. If you find the results on 3 different sites all being the same, you win and continue your project.

Comment: @spin_eight It's not always practical to rely purely on the standard. Many times, the information you want is not spelled out in the standard but must be pieced together from the interaction between multiple passages. Other times it can just be time consuming to find *where* the information is written. It's fine to be curious and try to find that information, but I think Christohper's point is that in practice it's also fine to rely on reliable sources like cppreference.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz: Regardless of why people do or do not pay for the standard, it is the definition of the language (including the standard library), and it definitely should specify the return type of `erase`. (And as we can see from NathanOliver's answer, it does.)

Comment: @ChristopherPisz: There's absolutely nothing wrong with wanting to get information from the definitive source. If you're not interested, that's fine, but it's a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The information is in a slightly un-intuitive place.  What `erase` returns is detailed under the sequence containers section of general container requirements section, specificly [[sequence.reqmts]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/sequence.reqmts#11)

> The iterator returned from `a.erase(q)` points to the element immediately following `q` prior to the element being erased. If no such element exists, `a.end()` is returned.

and [[sequence.reqmts]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/sequence.reqmts#12)

> The iterator returned by `a.erase(q1, q2)` points to the element pointed to by `q2` prior to any elements being erased. If no such element exists, `a.end()` is returned.

Comment: Just to make sure I get this right:  You say: The iterator returned from a.erase(q) points to the element immediately following q prior to the element being erased. If no such element exists, a.end() is returned.                      
                                                                                                                     
 Which I interpret as:  The iterator returned from a.erase(q) points to the element immediately following q and then q is erased. If no such element exists, a.end() is returned.  Just trying to learn something here...

Comment: @Drt The iterator returned will point to element immediately after the element(s) that were erased.  If there is no such element (erased the last element in the vector) then it returns `end()`.

Comment: @Drt See Dalle's answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector for the usage in a loop to see why it works the way it works.