# What iterator does vector::erase() return if passed an empty range?

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) and [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/), the function `std::erase(first, last)` returns "an iterator following the last removed element".

However, it is unclear what the return value is in the special case when there is no removed element at all, that is, when `first == last` (empty range). As of Jan 19, 2020, none of the above sources mention this special case.

For example, in the following code:

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4};
auto it1 = v.erase(v.begin(), v.begin());
auto it2 = v.erase(v.end(), v.end());
```

What will be the value of `it1` and `it2`?

Comment: Note: just found this almost duplicate (more general version, not just about empty range): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52301100/what-is-return-value-from-stdvector-erase-operator-according-to-the-standard?rq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is specified in [[sequence.reqmts]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/sequence.reqmts#12):

> The iterator returned by `a.erase(q1, q2)` points to the element pointed to by `q2` prior to any elements being erased. If no such element exists, `a.end()` is returned.

<sub>(Note: I linked the C++17 final working draft, but this wording exists since at least C++98, see comment by @Peter)</sub>

So we should have `it1 == v.begin()` and `it2 == v.end()`.

[Live test](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4952146b1ec9a62):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4};
    auto it1 = v.erase(v.begin(), v.begin());
    auto it2 = v.erase(v.end(), v.end());
    std::cout << std::distance(v.begin(), it1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::distance(v.begin(), it2) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
0
4
```

To clarify this behavior, I have updated the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) documentation, which is now:

> ```
> iterator erase( const_iterator pos );
> iterator erase( const_iterator first, const_iterator last );
> ```
>
> **Return Value**
>
> Iterator following the last removed element.
>
> If pos refers to the last element, then the end() iterator is returned.
>
> If last==end() prior to removal, then the updated end() iterator is returned.
>
> If [first, last) is an empty range, then last is returned.

Comment: Sounds like someone should edit the relevant cppreference page to document the expected behaviour here.

Comment: This isn't specific to the C++17 final working draft.  Identical wording is in the first C++ standard  (ISO/IEC 14882, First Edition 1998-09-01, Section 23.1.1 [lib.sequence.reqmts], para 8).   The preceding para 7 makes a similar statement for the single-argument form of `erase` - "The iterator returned from `a.erase(q)` points to the element immediately following `q` prior to the element being erased. If no such element exists, `a.end()` is returned."

Comment: @Peter Thx for the additional info! C++17 just happened to be the one I checked to answer the question. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Historical note: in some [old HP STL version](http://stepanovpapers.com/STL/DOC.PDF) the return type of `vector::erase` was just `void`.