# C++ erase if exist

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to remove element from container with an idempotent approach (i.e, if the element exist, then remove it, otherwise do nothing, and I can do this as many time as I want and the outcome is the same)

As far a I know, doing map::erase is idempotent, even the key is no exist it's also safe. I think `set` is the same.

Then what about vector (and similair linear container)?
I know this works well:

```
auto it = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), val);

if (it != vec.end())
  vec.erase(it);
```

But I'm wondering if there is any approach that we don't have to check `it == vec.end()`  manually?

According to cpp document, the behavior of `vec.erase(vec.end())` is not defined, which means we can not do `vec.erase(std::find(..))`.
Is there any method will do this check for me so that I can do `remove_if_exist` with one line code?

Comment: Why not [`remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) instead of this `find`/`erase` approach? Is it that you want to remove one entry and one entry only? You could put that in your "if" clause.

Comment: What do you want to do if there are multiple equivalent values, remove all of them or just one? Are you aware of the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Erasing elements from a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector)

Comment: "One line code" or "one statement code"? You can get a lot into a `for`...

Comment: FWIW, starting in C++17 you could write it as `if (auto it = std::find(...); it != vec.end()) vec.erase(it);`

Comment: @NathanOliver in earlier versions, you should be able to do this: `if ((auto it = std::find(...)) != vec.end()) vec.erase(it);`.  Prior to C++11, you would just have to replace `auto` with `vector<type>::iterator` instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is not one of idempotency. It is one of data access model.

The associative containers (set, map, etc) are different from sequences, because they have "keys" and that's why you can do lookup-by-key and erase operations all in one go.

Sequences don't have keys, so your comparison is unfair. Note that the equivalent operation on an associative container (i.e. lookup by mapped value — ignore set because weirdly its key *is* its value!) is equally verbose as with a sequence container.

That being said, [the erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) is indeed annoyingly cumbersome (this is done to separate "ranges" from their parent containers, in as many algorithms as possible; but still, meh). There's no reason `remove_and_erase` can't exist, but you'll have to make it yourself by combining `remove` and `erase` in a utility function.

Comment: See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/vector/erase_if

Answer (score 3):

> Then what about vector (and similair linear container)? I know this works well:

You know wrong. Code that you show is not idempotent either, as subsequent calls can modify the same vector multiple times. So really idempotent call would be:

```
vec.erase( std::remove( vec.begin(), vec.end(), val ), vec.end() );
```

and it is one liner as you wanted it to be.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   vector<int> vec {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

   vector<int>::iterator it;

   ((it = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 1)) == vec.end()) ? it : vec.erase(it);

   for(int i : vec) 
     cout << i << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (auto it = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 1); it != vec.end()) vec.erase(it);` :D

Comment: Using the conditional operator as an `if` statement is definitely an antipattern; avoid!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That is the way I would do it unfortunately that requires C++17 and this is tagged as C++11

Comment: @NathanOliver Lightness-To-English dictionary says _":D interj. I'm just being cheeky."_