# Memory leaks in a pointer vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, memory-leaks

I'm making a program that uses plenty of vectors containing pointers and I'm concerned that the way i delete the pointers might cause memory leaks down the line.

Here's for example how I add a bullet to the vector:

```
Bullet* aNewBullet;
aNewBullet = new Bullet(x,y,dirX,dirY,size,duration);
aNewBullet->assignTexture(btext);
bulletVector.push_back(aNewBullet);
```

And here's how i delete bullets from the vector (for example, if it exceeds its range)

```
int i=0;
while (i<bulletVector.size()){
    if (bulletVector[i]->getDuration() ==0)
        bulletVector.erase(bulletVector.begin() + i);
    else i++;
}
```

Am I deleting the bullet by telling the vector to erase?
Or should i do

```
int i=0;
while (i<bulletVector.size()){
    if (bulletVector[i]->getDuration() ==0)
        delete bulletVector[i];
        bulletVector.erase(bulletVector.begin() + i);
    else i++;
}
```

instead? Does this mess up the vector size by deleting the pointer first, and then deleting the record from the vector again?

Also does deleting the pointer call the bullet destructor (~Bullet())?

Comment: Do you need to use `new`/`delete`? Why not just use `std::vector<Bullet>`?

Comment: Collections of raw pointers are just not a good idea. Either the collection owns the objects pointed to or it doesn't. If it does own them, why use pointers at all? If it doesn't own them, managing the lifetime of the objects becomes very complicated.

Answer (score 2):

In the first code example you are not deleting any `Bullet` object. Erasing `vector` does only remove the pointers, not delete the pointed to object.

Your second example does properly delete `Bullet`s (not all of them given the conditionals and loop setup), but only if you do the necessary deletion at all points where the vector is modified and manually assure that a pointer is never deleted twice (e.g. because it is present in two vectors). This is not how containers are supposed to be used.

If you really want to store pointers and have the vector own them, then you should use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bullet>>` which will properly delete the `Bullet` objects when the vector is erased. However the vector will become non-copyable (only movable).

If however the vector is supposed own the `Bullet`s anyway, then you can simply store them directly in the vector: `std::vector<Bullet>`

If the vector is not supposed to own the `Bullet`s then the duty to delete them lies with whatever object is actually owning them, but even then there needs to be some effort made to assure deleted pointers do not remain in the vector.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `delete` the objects you've created with `new` (unless you surrender the pointer to a `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`). Consider letting the vector be the owner of the objects instead.

```
std::vector<Bullet> bulletVector;

// in C++17, emplace_back returns a ref to the new Bullet:
Bullet& aNewBullet = bulletVector.emplace_back(x,y,dirX,dirY,size,duration);

// pre C++17:
bulletVector.emplace_back(x,y,dirX,dirY,size,duration);
Bullet& aNewBullet = bulletVector.back();

aNewBullet.assignTexture(btext);
```

When you now `erase()` an object from the vector, it will be destructed automatically.

Comment: the vector is declared as vector<Bullet*> bulletVector; in the class, is removing the asterisk correct?

Comment: No, I suggested that OP should consider declaring it `std::vector<Bullet> bulletVector;` instead - if it doesn't mess up the rest of the design of course.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is *highly* likely you problem is solvable by not using manual dynamic allocation in the first place. There are reasons where you can use dynamic allocation (a polymorphic storage, for example), but even then you should steer toward smart pointers rather than manual allocations.

**Ditch the pointers**

To do this with a regular vector of concrete objects (not pointers), you would simply

```
std::vector<Bullet> bulletVector;
```

Additions could be done with something like this:

```
bulletVector.emplace_back(x,y,dirX,dirY,size,duration);
bulletVector.back().assignTexture(btext);
```

Removing all elements based on duration reaching zero would simply use the [remove/erase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector) idiom like this:

```
bulletVector.erase(std::remove_if(
                    bulletVector.begin(), 
                    bulletVector.end(),
                    [](auto const& b) { return b.getDuration() == 0; }),
                   bulletVector.end());
```

Keep in mind, while this is easily the preferred method for storing these things, it will require changes in the rest of your code. Everywhere you currently do this:

```
bulletVector[i]->doSomething();
```

will become

```
bulletVector[i].doSomething();
```

---

**More Intelligent Pointers**

If you must use dynamic allocation, *don't use manually managed pointers*. They're a recipe for memory leaks and ownership responsibility, and if you think it can't happen to you, you're being naive. Rather, use smart pointers. The two main smart pointer templates are [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). There is also [`std::weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr), which deserve an honorable mention, as it comes in very handy in certain situations (not yours, that I can tell).

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Bullet>> bulletVector;
```

Hence additions can be done like this (assuming this is done with polymorphism in mind and there may be more than one bullet type, in this case `MagicBullet` and `SilverBullet`, both derived from `Bullet`):

```
std::shared_ptr<Bullet> bullet = std::make_shared<MagicBullet>(x,y,dirX,dirY,size,duration);
bullet->assignTexture(btext);
bulletVector.emplace_back(bullet);

bullet = std::make_shared<SilverBullet>(x,y,dirX,dirY,size,duration);
bullet->assignTexture(btext);
bulletVector.emplace_back(bullet);
```

or just store regular bullets:

```
bullet = std::make_shared<Bullet>(x,y,dirX,dirY,size,duration);
bullet->assignTexture(btext);
bulletVector.emplace_back(bullet);
```

The removal algorithm is identical, only the condition predicate function changes (and not by much)

```
bulletVector.erase(std::remove_if(
                    bulletVector.begin(), 
                    bulletVector.end(),
                    [](auto const& b) { return b->getDuration() == 0; }),
                   bulletVector.end());
```

The nicest part of this is the remainder of your code will likely require little to no changes whatsoever. But I stress, that's the *only* real benefit (apart form the obvious, namely not having to manage the memory yourself any longer).

---

Given the choice between the two methods (vector of concrete objects vs vector of smart pointers) choose carefully. If the former works, use it. If it doesn't, either think about how it *could* work, or use the latter.

But above all, *stop managing memory manually*.

Comment: Personally I would want to recommend `std::unique_ptr` over `std::shared_ptr` as `std::shared_ptr`s come with their own set of problems and should only be used when actual *shared ownership* is required (two or more objects need to reference the same object and it is impossible to know which will die last).

Comment: @Galik  Certainly the appropriate use case should use the appropriate pointer type. There is zero evidence in the OP's code that the instances will be unique, and shared will work in both cases. If they indeed are unique, then the only reason to use a smart pointer at all (as opposed to concrete objects) is for polymorphic reasons (which there is likewise, zero evidence is required, but is an important unknown). Regardless, the concept is the same.

Answer (score -1):

Of course, you must deleting Bullets by yourself by delete. But your deletion cycle is not correct.

To delete values from vector with some condition, use something like this:

```
auto condFunc = [](const Bullet* x)
{
    bool rez = (x->getDuration() == 0);
    if(rez)
        delete x;
    return rez;
};
bulletVector.erase(std::remove_if(bulletVector.begin(), bulletVector.end(), condFunc), bulletVector.end());
```

Comment: Your example code doesn't delete the pointees either though, despite being a nicer way to erase them from the vector.

Comment: @PeteKirkham this example was "To delete values from vector", not to free memory

Comment: In that case it doesn't answer the question, which was about both removing them from the vector and deleting them from the heap. In C++ there is no such thing as 'deleting values from a vector' as 'delete' has a very specific meaning.