# C++ works fine at my computer but gets address sanitizer heap-buffer-overflow errors on leetcode

Tags: c++

I was trying to solve leetcode problem "929. Unique Email Addresses", the code works fine at my computer on Visual Studio Code but when I pasted it on the leetcode, I got address sanitizer heap-buffer-overflow error. The code is shown below:

```cpp
class Solution {
 public:
  int numUniqueEmails(vector<string>& emails) {
    string::iterator it;
    for (int i = 0; i < emails.size(); i++) {
      for (it = emails[i].begin(); *it != '@'; it++) {
        if (*it == '.') {
          emails[i].erase(it);
          it--;
        }
        if (*it == '+') {
          while (*it != '@') {
            emails[i].erase(it);
          }
          break;
        }
      }
      sort(emails.begin(), emails.end());
      for (int j = 0; j < emails.size(); j++) {
        if (emails[j] == emails[j + 1]) {
          emails.erase(emails.begin() + j);
          j--;
        }
      }
    }
    return emails.size();
  }
};
```

Can someone let me know why the error occurs?

Comment: `emails[j] == emails[j+1]` in a loop enumerating the entire container is not going to bode well when hitting up the last entry in the list at `emails[j]`. Ask yourself what is at `emails[j+1]` in that case. Frankly, since you already sorted the sequence, why you're not using [remove-erase idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector) is the real question.

Comment: What happens with the loop `for(it = emails[i].begin(); *it!='@'; it++)` is the string *doesn't* contain a `'@'` character?

Comment: Also what happens if the string starts with `.` ?

Answer (score 1):

Because the following loops:

```
for (it = emails[i].begin(); *it != '@'; it++)
   ...
```

and

```
while (*it != '@')
  ...
```

iterate with `it` over the string without never ever verifying if the end of the string was reached.  If you have a single ill-formatted email address in the input data, you therefore go out of bounds.  So UB.

In addition, you also go out of bounds here:

```
 for (int j = 0; j < emails.size(); j++) {
    if (emails[j] == emails[j + 1]) {  // what when j == size-1 ????
```

Finally a potentially nasty issue as well (but could affect the result):  your first `for` loop should end before the `sort()`.  Why?  because with some bad luck, the sorting will change the order of the elements, causing an unprocessed address to move before the current i index and thus remain unprocessed.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/cZEFBY) with some additional display of intermediary results and some extreme cases.

Comment: It helps a lot! Thank you!