# Using C++'s `str.erase()` from within Cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am implemeting a function in Cython that requires, at some point to remove some `char` from a C++ `std::string`. For this, I would use `std::string::erase()`. However, when I try to use it, Cython forces the object to be `bytes()` instead of `std::string()`, at which point it cannot find `.erase()`.

To illustrate the issue, here is a minimal example (using IPython + Cython magic):

```py
%load_ext Cython
```

```py
%%cython --cplus -c-O3 -c-march=native -a


from libcpp.string cimport string


cdef string my_func(string s):
    cdef char c = b'\0'
    cdef size_t s_size = s.length()
    cdef size_t i = 0
    while i + 1 <= s_size:
        if s[i] == c:
            s.erase(i, 1)
        i += 1
    return s


def cy_func(string b):
    return my_func(b)
```

This compiles, but it indicates Python interaction on the `.remove()` line, and when I try to use it, e.g.

```py
b = b'ciao\0pippo\0'
print(b)
cy_func(b)
```

I get:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>   AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'erase'
>
> Exception ignored in: '_cython_magic_5beaeb4004c3afc6d85b9b158c654cb6.my_func'
>   AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'erase'

How could I solve this?

## Notes

1. If I replace the `s.erase(i, 1)` with say `s[i] == 10`, I get `my_func()` with no Python interaction (can even use the `nogil` directive).
2. I know I could this in Python with `.replace(b'\0', b'')`, but it is part of a longer algorithm I hope to optimize with Cython.

Comment: Try using string.replace rather than string.erase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why Cython produces code it is producing - there is even no `erase` in [string.pxd](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libcpp/string.pxd), so Cython should be producing an error.

The easiest workaround would be to introduce a function `erase` which wrapps `std::string::erase`:

```
cdef extern from *:
    """
    #include <string>
    std::string &erase(std::string& s, size_t pos, size_t len){
        return s.erase(pos, len);
    }
    """
    string& erase(string& s, size_t pos, size_t len)

# replace  s.erase(i,1) -> erase(s,i,1)
```

However, it is not how erasing zeros should be done in C++:  it is buggy (see @M.S. [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56818688/5769463) for a fix) and it has `O(n^2)` running time (just try it on `b"\x00"*10**6`), the right way is to use [remove/erase-idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/347478/5769463):

```
%%cython --cplus
from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef extern from *:
    """
    #include <string>
    #include <algorithm>
    void remove_nulls(std::string& s){
       s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), 0), s.end());
    }
    """
    void remove_nulls(string& s)


cdef string my_func(string s):
    remove_nulls(s)
    return s
```

which is hard to misuse and is `O(n)`.

---

One more remark, concerning passing `std::string' per value. The signature:

```
cdef string my_func(string s)
     ...
     return s
```

means, there are two (unnecessary) copies (with RVO being impossible), it might  be better to avoid and pass `s` by reference (at least in `cdef`-functions):

```
def cy_func(string b):
    remove_nulls(b)  # no copying
    return b
```

Comment: hi ead, just wondering, what you mean by "RVO being impossible"? Cython compiled code does not offer return optimization?

Comment: @WillianFuks, when you take a look at the generated cpp-code for `my_fun`  you will see, that it doesn't use copy constructor, but default-constructor+assignment operator - but RVO  can elide one the copy constructor. Ok, in this particular case where everything gets inlined the compiler will probably be able to optimize everything, but in generel this is not the case.

Comment: Thanks! I'll adapt my code to just use functions with input references then. Seems to be the most reliable approach.

Answer (score 1):

You get access after the array bounds. Fix it, and your code will be working.

The length of the string is decreased after `erase`. Also the condition   `i < s_size` looks better than `i + 1 <= s_size`. Finally, `i` must not be incremented after `erase`, the new char comes to that index.

```
while i < s_size:
    if s[i] == c:
        s.erase(i, 1)
        s_size -= 1
    else:
        i += 1
```

`b` below is the byte array. Try to call `.decode` to convert it to string.

```
b = b'ciao\0pippo\0'
print(b)
cy_func(b.decode('ASCII'))
```

Comment: I copy-pasted your code but it gives me the exact same error.

Comment: @norok2 I've updated my answer with the additional change of your code.

Comment: It still does not work. The most important bit is that it does not follow the specified type and goes with `bytes()` instead of C++'s `string`