# memory out of range Vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I'm writing this program why it throws an error in `toupper('a')`?

```
void test2(void) {
  string n;
  vector<string> v;
  auto it = v.begin();
  do {
    cout << "Enter a name of a fruit: ";
    cin >> n;
    v.push_back(n);
  } while (n != "Quit");
  v.erase(v.end() - 1);
  sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](string g, string l) { return g < l; });
  dis(v);

  for (auto i : v) {
    if (i.at(0) == toupper('a')) {
      cout << i << endl;
      v.erase(remove(v.begin(), v.end(), i));
    }
  }
  dis(v);
}
```

Can someone help me to find the error?

Comment: don't erase inside a loop, that just calls for trouble.

Comment: BTW why don't you write `A` which is the same as `toupper('a')`?? Are you sure thie condition ist what you want:`(i.at(0) == toupper('a'))` ? Is this what you want: `(toupper(i.at(0)) == 'A')`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector

Comment: Don't modify a vector while you're range-looping over it. It will cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes, if I remove ```v.erase(remove(v.begin(), v.end(), i));``` it works fine

Comment: @molbdnilo how can i delete that element then

Comment: @Ayxan, I've tried this but it doesn't work

Comment: @Idriss you should be more specific about how it didn't work for you, so we can help

Comment: Are you sure that all the `string`s in your `vector` aren't empty? If you have an empty `string` using `at` will throw an `std::out_of_range` exception.

Comment: Now it's ok, but it didn't remove all the strings start with 'a'
```for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
 {
  if(toupper(it->at(0))=='A')
   v.erase(remove(v.begin(), v.end(), *it));
 }```

Comment: @Idriss That's the wrong loop.

Comment: @molbdnilo how?

Comment: @Idriss Didn't any of the answers you've gotten solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Since you already tried to implement the erase-remove-idiom, that's how it can be used in this case:

```
v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const std::string &item) {
        return std::toupper(item.at(0)) == 'A';
}), v.end());
```

Here I assumed, that `i.at(0) == toupper('a')` is a typo and should be `toupper(i.at(0)) == 'A'`.

Comment: OPs code removes only `A`, yours `a` and `A`. It is likely that this is what OP actually wants, but maybe worth a note

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yes, I assumed it would be a  typo on OPs side, since WBucks answer handles it the same way.

Answer (score 3):

Write your deletion loop like this:

```
for ( auto it = std::begin( v ); it != std::end( v ); )
{ 
    if ( toupper( it->at( 0 ) ) == 'A' )
        it = v.erase( it );
    else 
        ++it;
}
```

If you do it the way you're doing it you'll invalidate the `iterator` and then never reassign it a valid `iterator` which is needed to correctly loop through the `vector`.

Comment: Thank you, why like this way? why you wrote it=begin(v) and not it=v.begin()?

Comment: A non-throwing alternative: `if (not it->empty() && toupper( (*it)[0] ) == 'A' )`

Comment: @Idriss Honestly, 6 in one, half dozen in the other. I like using the free functions but thats my personal preference

Comment: @TedLyngmo I considered that, but I think that'll just muddy the waters.

Comment: @WBuck but if the condition is true, 'it' won't increase! it's weird , I can't understand, can you explain a little bit please

Comment: @Idriss see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase `erase` will return an iterator to the element after the one that was removed.

Comment: @Idriss When you call `erase` it returns an `iterator following the last removed element`. In other words, it returns an `iterator` pointing to the next element in the `vector`.

Comment: @WBuck :o that's awesome thank you guys

Comment: sorry for the nitpick, "If you do it the way you're doing it you'll invalidate the iterator."  you are also invalidating the iterator `it`, it just doesn't matter because in the same line you again assign a valid iterator to `it`. The iterator is invalidated in any case, the actual problem is using the invalidated iterator

Comment: @idclev463035818 True, regardless the `iterator` is being invalidated. Just it's being immediately reassigned a valid `iterator`. I was just trying to keep it as simple as possible. Thats also why I didn't show the `erase-remove-idiom`, just to keep it simple

Comment: simple is completely ok with me, but your last sentence suggests that in your code no iterator is invalidated, which is not "simple" but wrong ;)

Comment: suggestion: If you do it the way you're doing it the range based loops is working on invalidated iterators

Comment: @idclev463035818 I changed the verbiage of the last line to better explain whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here :

```
for (auto i : v) {
  if (i.at(0) == toupper('a')) {
    cout << i << endl;
    v.erase(remove(v.begin(), v.end(), i));
  }
}
```

is that you are modifying the vector inside the loop with `erase()` which invalidates the iterators used internally to implement the for range loop.

The loop is a syntactic sugar for something like this :

```
{

auto&& range = v;
auto&& first = std::begin(v); // obtained once before entering the loop
auto&& last = std::end(v); // obtained once before entering the loop

for (; first != last; ++first)
{
    auto i = *first; // first will be invalid the next time after you call erase()
    if (i.at(0) == toupper('a')) {
        cout << i << endl;
        v.erase(remove(v.begin(), v.end(), i)); // you are invalidating the iterators and then dereferencing `first` iterator at the beginning of the next cycle of the loop
    }
}

}
```

Why calling `erase()` invalidates the vector ?
This is because a vector is like a dynamic array which stores its capacity (whole array size) and size (current elements count), and iterators are like pointers which point to elements in this array

So when `erase()` is called it will rearrange the array and decrease its size, so updating the `end` iterator and your `first` iterator will not be pointing to the next item in the array as you intended . This illustrates the problem :

```
std::string* arr = new std::string[4];
std::string* first = arr;
std::string* last = arr + 3;

void erase(std::string* it)
{
    std::destroy_at(it);
}

for (; first != last; ++first)
{
    if (some_condition)
        erase(first); // the last element in the array now is invalid
    // thus the array length is now considered 3 not 4
    // and the last iterator should now be arr + 2
    // so you will be dereferencing a destoryed element since you didn't update your last iterator
}
```

What to learn from this ?
Never do something which invalidates the iterators inside for range loop.

Solution:
Update iterators at each cycle so you always have the correct bounds :

```
auto&& range = v;
auto&& first = std::begin(v); // obtained once before entering the loop
auto&& last = std::end(v); // obtained once before entering the loop

for (; first != last;)
{
    auto i = *first;
    if (i.at(0) == toupper('a'))
    {
        first = v.erase(remove(v.begin(), v.end(), i));
        last = std::end(v);
    }
    else
    {
        ++first;
    }
}
```

Comment: that's great! but what's the meaning of invalidate an iterator?

Comment: To invalidate an iterator is to have it pointing to something that is invalid . For example a pointer pointing to a freed heap object or a pointer that points to an element that is out of the array bounds . generally you can think of iterators as pointers , in fact pointers are already iterators