# fatal error: no member named 'find' in 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >'

Tags: c++

Can someone tell why am I getting this error

```
fatal error: no member named 'find' in 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >'
         if(people.find(people.begin(),people.end(),x)!=people.end())
```

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#define REP(i,a,b) for(int i=a ; i<b ; i++)
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n,m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    vector<vector<int>> friends;
    vector<int> people;
    vector<int> cost_of_person;
    REP(i,0,n){
        cin >> cost_of_person[i];
        people.push_back(i+1);
    }
    REP(i,0,m){
        int x,y;
        cin >> x >> y;
        if(people.find(people.begin(),people.end(),x)!=people.end()) // error here
            people.erase(x);
        if(people.find(people.begin(),people.end(),y)!=people.end())
            people.erase(y);
        bool inserted = false;
        REP(j,0,friends.size())
        .
        .
        .
        .


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, that's because [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) class doesn't have any member function called `find()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Erasing elements from a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector)

Comment: Generally, you can also use ```std::find``` in conjunction with a vector,
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/

Comment: All containers in the std only have the absolute minimum of member functions that are required to control their contents. Everything else is done with free functions, that provide a container independent interface using iterators.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) does not have a `find()` member method.  You need to use the [`std::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) algorithm instead:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

if (std::find(people.begin(), people.end(), x) != people.end())
    people.erase(x);
if (std::find(people.begin(), people.end(), y) != people.end())
    people.erase(y);
```

However, you will then get a new error, because [`std::vector::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) does not take an *element value* as input, it takes an *iterator* instead.  So you need to fix that, too:

```cpp
vector<int>::iterator iter = std::find(people.begin(), people.end(), x);
if (iter != people.end())
    people.erase(iter);
iter = std::find(people.begin(), people.end(), y);
if (iter != people.end())
    people.erase(iter);
```

Another problem I see with your code is you are not adding elements to your `cost_of_person` vector correctly, corrupting memory.  You have two choices to fix that:

- resize `cost_of_person` before entering the loop:

  ```cpp
  vector<int> cost_of_person(n);
  REP(i,0,n){
      ...
  }
  ```

  Or

  ```cpp
  vector<int> cost_of_person;
  cost_of_person.resize(n);
  REP(i,0,n){
      ...
  }
  ```
- use `cost_of_person.push_back()` inside the loop:

  ```cpp
  vector<int> cost_of_person;
  REP(i,0,n){
      int cost;
      cin >> cost;
      cost_of_person.push_back(cost);
      people.push_back(i+1);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

> ```
> if(people.find(people.begin(),people.end(),x)!=people.end())
> ```

You are using member function of object `people` named `find`. However, it turns out that `people` is defined as:

> ```
> vector<int> people;
> ```

It is a vector. And that type doesn't have a member function named `find`. Because you call a non-existing member function, the program is ill-formed. As a consequence, you get a diagnostic message from the compiler:

> fatal error: no member named 'find' in 'std::vector >'

To fix it, don't call functions that don't exist.