# C++ Remove vector items that exist in another vector WHILE retaining order

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

```
std::vector<int> items = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<int> removeItems = {2, 4};
```

I need to delete the values in `items` that are in `removeItems`, while retaining the order of `items`. Something like this:

`items.remove(removeItems);`

Output

> items = {1, 3, 5}

Are there any built in vector methods that can achieve this? I haven't found any that accept another vector of items to remove. If not, whats the most efficient way of achieving this?

Edit

[Erasing elements from a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector/347478#347478)
This post refers to removing one item at a time, I'm looking to delete a whole bunch at once in a more compact way then

```
for(num in removeItems) {
    items.erase(std::remove(items.begin(), items.end(), num), items.end())
}
```

Because surely this way of removing items is very inefficient because you have to check the entire `items` vector twice (`removeItems.size()`) for each item in `removeItems`

Edit 2

Number of elements in `items` or `removeItems` will be in the range 0-10000

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/347478/783510 I think you are looking for the so called "remove/erase" idiom

Comment: @PhilippClaßen No as they are removing individual members at a time. I'm looking to do it all at once

Comment: _"I'm looking to delete a whole bunch at once in a more compact way then"_ It just composes... put it in a function!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient general form is to turn `removeItems` into an unordered set, and then remove elements from `items` by checking for membership.

```
std::unordered_set<int> removeSet(removeItems.begin(), removeItems.end());
items.erase(std::remove_if(items.begin(), items.end(), [&](int x) {
    return removeSet.count(x) != 0;
}), items.end());
```

If `removeItems` is small a linear scan is probably faster than turning it into an unordered set. For large `removeItems` the above is the most efficient, unless it has a very special form (such as only having small elements).

If both arrays are already sorted (like they are in your example, assuming that isn't coincidence) you can do even better than the above.

Comment: To be honest, with such a small `removeItems`, it's probably faster to just stick with the vector and do an _O(n*m)_ search sequence.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Possibly, but I don't know how large the *real* `removeItems` is. This solution scales linearly with any amount of `items`/`removeItems`, whereas keeping the vector is quadratic.

Comment: Yes, it scales, but has worse _actual_ performance until you have many elements to remove. When writing code we should consider reality not just theoretical extensions. At the very least the answer should mention this.

Comment: @cdhowie It doesn't need to?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm, I had a hunch sets might have something to do with it!

Answer (score 2):

You can apply [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom), with help of [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and  [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

```
std::vector<int> items = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<int> removeItems = {2, 4};
items.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(items),
                           std::end(items),
                           [&removeItems](auto i) { return std::find(std::begin(removeItems), std::end(removeItems), i) != std::end(removeItems); }),
            std::end(items));
```

Note that `std::remove_if` just shifts the elements to be removed to the back of the `vector`; these elements are erased by [`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) later at a time.