# Remove object from vector if private variable matches

Tags: c++, vector

I have a class Inventory

```
class Inventory {
    private:
        vector<Item> items;
    public:
        void addItem(Item item) {
            items.push_back(item);
        }

        void removeItem(string n) {
            # Complete this
        }
}
```

And a class Item

```
class Item {
    private:
        string name;
        int power;
    public:
        Item(string n, int p) {
            name = n; power = p;
        }
        
        string getName(){
            return name;
        }
};
```

how can I remove an item from `items` if the name of the `Item` is equal to a string `n`?

something like:

```
bool matches(string name, Item item){
    if (name == item.getName()) return true;

    return false;
}

find_if(items.begin(), items.end() matches(someVariable, someObject));
```

TL;DR I need to remove an object from a vector if the value of a variable inside the object is equal to a variable passed to the function

Comment: In C++11, this is what lambdas are for. Before C++11, you will have to do more work. Whichever version of C++ you can use, your C++ textbook should have plenty of examples of accomplishing this basic, fundamental task. All C++ textbooks cover this topic. Is there anything in your textbook's explanation that's unclear to you?

Comment: erase-remove https://stackoverflow.com/a/347478/1766544 see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom

Comment: what if two items have the same name? Have you considered implementing the inventory class using `unordered_map/map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of doing this is to use the combination of `std::remove` / `std::remove_if` and `erase`.

You can find the documentation in the CPP Reference [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase). In the `std::remove` example code, you can see also the combination of remove and erase. You can also find tons of similar examples here on SO.

`std::remove_if` will use a simple lambda that checks, if the item name matches the search name.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Item {
private:
    std::string name;
    int power;
public:
    Item(std::string n, int p) {
        name = n; power = p;
    }

    std::string getName() {
        return name;
    }
};
class Inventory {
private:
    std::vector<Item> items;
public:
    void addItem(Item item) {
        items.push_back(item);
    }

    void removeItem(std::string n) {
        items.erase(std::remove_if(items.begin(), items.end(), [n](Item& i) { return i.getName() == n; }), items.end());
    }
};

int main() {

    Inventory inventory{};

    // Add 20 item as a demo
    for (int i{}; i < 20; ++i) inventory.addItem(Item(std::to_string(i), i));

    // Remove Item "3"
    inventory.removeItem("3");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The original way as follow.

```cpp
void removeItem(string n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i) {
        if (items[i].getName() == n) {
            items.erase(items.begin() + i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```