# Valgrind showing invalid read of size 4 when using an erase function

Tags: c++, vector, runtime-error, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I am writing an assignment that utilizes a vector class that I had to make that mimics the standard Vector file for c++. In my program, I am trying to filter intervals for showing more than once. When I run through, I get the results I want, but with a RTE error and these accompanying:

```
==672367== Invalid read of size 4
==672367==    at 0x109D0B: Vector::erase(int*) (Vector.cpp:357)
==672367==    by 0x10A4C8: main (pa13a.cpp:79)
==672367==  Address 0x4dc00a0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==672367==    at 0x483C583: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==672367==    by 0x10985C: Vector::operator=(Vector const&) (Vector.cpp:220)
==672367==    by 0x10A49F: main (pa13a.cpp:76)
==672367== 
Unique Timestamps:  [100, 200, 320, 480, 700]
Intervals:          [100, 120, 160, 220]
Filtered Intervals: [120, 160, 220]
Reversed Intervals: [220, 160, 120]
Combined Data:      [100, 200, 320, 480, 700, 220, 160, 120]
==672367== 
==672367== HEAP SUMMARY:
==672367==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==672367==   total heap usage: 27 allocs, 27 frees, 78,152 bytes allocated
==672367== 
==672367== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==672367== 
==672367== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==672367== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The section:

```
fInt = tInt; // Filtered interval = to Original Interval vector
    for (auto x = fInt.begin(); x != fInt.end(); ++x) { // pointer iteration
        while (*x == minInterval) { // value of position == the filter number
            fInt.erase(x); // erase duplicates until new number
        }
    }
```

Upon noticing, I tried iterating through using indexing, but got segmentation faults. I tried going through and saving individually then running through and reversing but got segmentation faults. The easiest method I can think of is this. Unless this is fine and it's my erase function in Vector class, but utilizing a test case file with similar values being inputted causes no alarms with valgrind on the class file alone.

Comment: `fInt.erase(x);` -- `++x` -- What do you think will happen if you erase the item, and then `++x` is called on the erased item `x`?

Comment: Instead of this loop, use the [erase-remove idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/how-can-you-erase-elements-from-a-vector-while-iterating).

Comment: valgrind is right there is a bug here, you are modifying a container while iterating over it.  Erase will often invalidate iterators (depends a bit on the container), so use with care. This is why C++ has std::remove_if + std:erase idiom

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie exactly :)

Comment: You are incrementing an iterator and shrinking the size of the vector simultaneously. That should make you pause and consider whether your code is OK. See the duplicate answer for various methods you can use that do work.